# Check input box on parent click with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of list items that contain an input field, when the list item is clicked, id like to check the child item, is this posisble?

```
function setupToptions() {
    if ($('ul.top-options input').length) {
        $('ul.top-options li').each(function(){ 
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $('ul.top-options li input:checked').each(function(){ 
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
        });                
    };
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Top options select
    $('ul.top-options li').click(function(){
        setupToptions();
    });
    setupToptions();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BKgdc/1/

Comment: So, just to clarify, when the red area is clicked (not the radio button) you want the radio button to be selected...?

Comment: Then @RichardDalton is the man =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the checked value on the child input like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Top options select
    $('ul.top-options li').click(function(){
        $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true); // Add this line     
        setupToptions();
    });
    setupToptions();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BKgdc/2/

Answer (score 1):

Not the best answer (because I've changed everything), but just one more possible solution without `setupToptions` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $li = $('ul.top-options li');
    $li.click(function() {
        $li.removeClass('active')
        .filter(this).addClass('active').find('input').prop('checked', true);
    });
    $li.filter(':has(:checked)').click();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BKgdc/4/

Answer (score 0):

you can do this very easily. just add this code .

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $(this).find("input").attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the code:

```
$('input', this).attr('checked', 'true');
```

To the `li` click function.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BKgdc/3/)

Answer (score 0):

A complete approach is to register the `click` of the parent, and the `change` of the radio button. It's also worth noting that this can be achieved without JavaScript, with the correct usage of `label`... but for sake of the question, here's the JavaScript.

```
// the click
function setChecked() {
    $('input', this).prop('checked', true).change();
}

// the change
function updateActive() {
    $('ul.top-options li').removeClass('active')
        .find('input:checked')
        .parent()
        .addClass('active');
}

// hooking it together
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.top-options li').click(setChecked).find('input').change(updateActive);
});
```

### [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/BKgdc/5/)